# google-chrome cursor extremely small in Gnome 3, google-chrome-dev is regular system size

Tags: gnome, gnome3, chrome

I am on latest Arch with latest Gnome 3. I had this working fine, but played with the native screen resolution and somehow after this exercise, my mouse cursor size is now super small in google-chrome. I tried resetting the theme multiple times including "use system theme and titlebars" with no luck. To debug, I installed google-chrome-dev, and it is working as expected. I am using the Adwaita dark theme in both Arch and Chrome.

I think I could solve this by reinstalling google-chrome but would like to debug this to figure out why google-chrome isn't honoring the gtk3 system value here.

Comment: Somehow it fixed itself. This morning it was small, but I just noticed now it is normal again. Would have loved to figure out what was happening here.

Answer (score 1):

The dev version contains proposed updates, upgrades and fixes. However it is more unstable than the Stable release. I would talk to a Chrome developer and ask what change in their code could do that.